# Regex for matching domain and ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

For my rails app I want a regex which will match domain and IP addresses.

Comment: As other posters have noted, your question is vague about what patterns you want to match.  Do you want to find URLs or just domain names?  Since there a lot of TLDs, almost anything with a dot in it could be a domain name: foo.com, foo.ac.uk, foo.info, foo.bar.bletch.mil, foo.de, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

`\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b`

Taken from [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).

EDIT: For domain names, you could use something like so: `^http://(.*?)/?.*`. However, it would help if you could post some domain name examples. The regex I have posted should match url which starts with `http://` and it will then throw the domain name, such as `google.com` in a group which you can then access later.

Comment: Thanks npinti, but it will match only ip address but it may fail when I enter domain name like http://google.com right?

Comment: @Harshal_m_joshi: yes you are correct. I have modified my answer, if you would post some sample domain names you are intending to match it would help in creating the respective regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking a URL, and trying to match the host part,

```
/^http:\/\/([^\/])\//
```

Comment: other protocols? shouldn't `/^[a-z]*:\/\/([^\/])\//` fit better?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need a regex for something, I first go to the [Regular Expressions Library](http://regexlib.com/).  It is there that I found this one that looks quite reasonable:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

I would use a separate regex for IP addresses and ask if the string matches either instead of trying to make both patterns fit a single matcher.

Answer (score 0):

^

I would say you need to be more specific, I also like to use http://www.rubular.com/
 to develop my regexs. It has a reference key under the editor so you can play with it. You can have fun and get your work done at the same time!